# How to use pdf reader Activex Control in c# winform when udpated to newest adobe software

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, activex

Several years ago, after searching internet I found a way to use pdf reader control in C# project, I am not quite sure for following steps since it's too long ago.

```
  First: of course you should install adobe reader software

  Then:  in Visual Studio C# winform project, you can Add Reference and find in COM Tag "pdf reader control", 
         after adding that, in project's reference tab, 2 more items added : AxAcroPDFLib and AcroPDFLib, and in ToolBox tab, 
         you can drag a PDFReader control to the form just like drag a textbox control, it will show pdf files

  Then: do some coding for this control to do your specific jobs
```

A few days ago, when I wanted to create a new project doing above steps again, I found although I can find similar pdf COM item, I can only create AcroPDFLib in reference tab, no AxAcroPDFLib, and No control in ToolBox , then I can not drag it to my form since no such control can be found, I reopened my old project, it can still be compiled and run normally, but still no pdf control in ToolBox, that is to say, if I delete my pdf control from my form, I can not add it again.

I guess maybe the reason is adobe software updated a lot since my old project,Currently above steps should be changed? But since the old project still can run normally,this pdf reader activex control maybe still can be used, but How? Thanks for any suggestions!